# How to check if numbers only increase in a group?

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse

I would like to check the column "state" within in a  group (ID) for to see if numbers are only increasing.

Example:

```
df <-data.frame("ID" = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                "State"=c(1,2,3,1,4,2))
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Check = ifelse(State > State[row.number() + 1], TRUE, FALSE)))
```

And the Output I was hoping for:
Check:
A - TRUE
B - FALSE (because in this example 1,4,2 the numbers increases but then decrease)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <-data.frame("ID" = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                "State"=c(1,2,3,1,4,2))

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(Check = all(diff(State) >= 0))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   ID    Check
#>   <chr> <lgl>
#> 1 A     TRUE 
#> 2 B     FALSE
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Check = all(diff(State) >= 0))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>   ID    State Check
#>   <chr> <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1 A         1 TRUE 
#> 2 A         2 TRUE 
#> 3 A         3 TRUE 
#> 4 B         1 FALSE
#> 5 B         4 FALSE
#> 6 B         2 FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Check Yuriy answer to see a more compact solution maybe harder to read if you do not know about `diff` and `all` function in the first place

---

### Code

```
require(tidyverse)

(
  df
  %>% group_by(ID)
  %>% mutate(Diff = State - lag(State))
  %>% filter(! is.na(Diff))
  %>% summarise(Increasing = all(Diff >= 0))
)
```

---

### Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  ID    Increasing
  <chr> <lgl>           
1 A     TRUE            
2 B     FALSE
```

---

### Explanation

```
(
  df
  %>% group_by(ID)
  %>% mutate(Diff = State - lag(State))
)

  ID    State  Diff
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1    NA
2 A         2     1
3 A         3     1
5 B         1    NA
6 B         4     3
7 B         2    -2
```

The difference with the upper line is computed in each subgroup

```
(
  df
  %>% group_by(ID)
  %>% mutate(Diff = State - lag(State))
  %>% filter(! is.na(Diff))
  %>% summarise( all(Diff >= 0))
)
```

The `NA` lines are deleted and then we have to check if a negative number is present.

---

### Data sample

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- tribble( ~ ID, ~ State,
                "A",       1,
                "A",       2,
                "A",       3,
                "B",       1,
                "B",       4,
                "B",       2
               )
```

Comment: there is actually a `diff` function which is the same as `State - lag(State)`

Comment: @Jack But the function does not return a vector of the same size, so ti is cumbersome to make it work.